# Url Rewrite HTTPS -> HTTP except certain page (IIS 7)

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Only one page, and all dependencies (css, jpg etc), is to be SSL for now.  I created the following rewrite:

```
  <rule name="Not Appointment Form 4.1 SSL" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" negate="false" />
      <conditions>
          <!-- check if https is on -->
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />

          <!-- I'm only interested in the aspx files -->
          <add input="{PATH_TRANSLATED}" pattern=".aspx$" /> 

          <!-- anything BUT the page to be secured -->
          <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="page-to-be-secured.aspx" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://mydomain{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

I've tried putting the name of the page in the match url (negate="false") and still doesn't work.

I've tested each individual condition and they all work individually, but as a whole it's not redirecting to the none-HTTPS page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
<rule name="Not Appointment Form 4.1 SSL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)\.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="page-to-be-secured" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The rule is applied to every requested url ending with `.aspx`. If the first back reference (`{R:1}`) corresponding to the part before `.aspx` doesn't match `page-to-be-secured` and is using `HTTPS`, then the redirect is triggered.

Comment: how do I do this for only www?

Comment: @tpbafk add a condition `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$"></conditions>`